# mysql reverse order of records fetching

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fetching the last 5 records inserted in the mysql table, in reverse order:

but with the following query i am unable to do that, i have read that a `subquery` can do it, but exactly where to apply, i am confused:

here is my table

```
select "1" as s,`to` as f, message as m,sent  
from table1 where chat.`to` = "user1" 
union 
select "1" as s,`to` as f, message as m,sent  
from table1 where chat.`from` = "user1" 
ORDER BY sent DESC
limit 5
```

Here is result currently

```
1   v         bbye              10  2014-09-12 02:17:06
1   Gv        not interested    9   2014-09-12 02:17:04
1   Get       football          8   2014-09-12 02:16:55
1   Get       let's play        7   2014-09-12 02:16:50
1   Gv        ok great work     6   2014-09-12 02:16:43
```

this is the below way i am trying to do

```
1   Gv        ok great work     6   2014-09-12 02:16:43
1   Get       let's play        7   2014-09-12 02:16:50
1   Get       football          8   2014-09-12 02:16:55
1   Gv        not interested    9   2014-09-12 02:17:04
1   v         bbye              10  2014-09-12 02:17:06
```

Comment: I think what is happening is that it would take bottom 5 from the second query, but all of the first query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subquery would be formatting like this:

```
select * from(
  select *
  from
   (select "1" as s,`to` as f, message as m,sent  
    from table1 where chat.`to` = "user1" 
    union 
    select "1" as s,`to` as f, message as m,sent  
    from table1 where chat.`from` = "user1" ) u
  ORDER BY sent DESC
  limit 5) o order by sent
```

As @GGio notes however, refactoring your query to use an `OR` would be more efficient:

```
select * from (
  SELECT "1" as s, `to` as f, message as m, sent
  FROM table1
  WHERE chat.`to` = "user1" OR chat.`from` = "user1"
  ORDER BY sent DESC
  LIMIT 5) o
order by sent
```

Comment: @voyeger, Now I understand what you are looking for.  I've created a subquery out of both of them, to order the outer one properly.